# C# DataBase choice to save information about 70.000 element

Tags: c#, database

**I have a project that  must be able to :**

- Collect information about medical plants(texts only the pictures are hosted elsewhere).
- Once done, preview those information and manipulate them as needed(For example, show only the names and description of plants from category A and having a life span of 2 years).

**Information about the project :**

- I'm using : **C#**
- The project will result in a desktop software that will run on **my
  personal computer only**.
- The number of plants is **70.000**.
- Every plant needs one **"A4"** page of information(name,description,...).

**What is the best Database choice in my case and why ?** 
(Is using an XML file as a DataBase a bad idea ?)
Thank you.

Comment: This is off-topic since it is asking for recommendations about what to use as datastorage medium?

Comment: Using XML may be envisaged in your context, specially, if you have very few DataTables. I won't recommend XML, it if you have a lot of relations between the different tables (except if they only refer to lookUp tables)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SqlExpress LocalDb, thats more than enough for your needs, yet still easily portable.

> P.S. This kind of questions are not welcome here, you should find a
>   Forum where you can discuss about pros and cons. If you have specific
>   questions about the implementation you are more than welcome to ask
>   here.